# URL Rewrite not working for multiple pages in same folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to improve another one of my parameter based urls. The first rewrite works, but the second fails to find relevant php based data:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/js
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/custom/contact
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html?$ /photography/viewphoto.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html?$ /photography/photoscollection.php?ref=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Anybody help?

UPDATE:
I currently have 5 pages containing photos, photoscollection01.html -> photoscollection05.html based on categories. The contents of the Categories are read fron an XML file. I decided to just have the single PHP file with a URL parameter representing the Category, i.e. ref.
From within one of these pages, a user can click a photo to view it, based on its id.
Therefore:
page containing photos.
/photography/photoscollection.php?ref=photos01 -> /photos01.html etc

view specific photo.
/photography/viewphoto.php?id=c01-a01-p01 -> /c01-a01-p01.html

Comment: Yes, because `RewriteEngine` is still on. You can then turn it off.

Comment: Thank you @AAShakil Shakil for your reply. I have turned off RewriteEngine and now get a 404 Error.

Comment: You either have the rewrite engine turned on, or you don’t – you can not “switch” between the two like that. And neither is it necessary, or would even be able to solve the problem you are having here.

Comment: You are trying to match the same URL pattern in both cases here - which is nonsense. I request `http://example.com/foo.html` - now is that photo id, or a collection reference? Wait, you can’t tell merely from looking at that URL? Well neither can your server.

Comment: @Barton Oh. Have your problem solved?

Comment: @AAShakil Shakil as CBroe has pointed it will not work, but really not sure how to fix this issue. Should I add a 2nd dummy parameter to create a new pattern, or move one of the files?

Comment: @Barton How can a same requested url could be rewrote to different?

Comment: @AAShakil Shakil I can get to a point where it renders the 2nd page, but all the pre-processing PHP stuff isn't working, functions that use the REF paramater aren't returning the correct values. Server stuff drives me nuts.

Comment: Can you provide a input URL for each case/rule?